# Twitter Group DM Api

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been using twitter api for a while and I'm still looking for some way to implement a download method for DMs at conversation DM.

My code looks like this in this moment:

```
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/direct_messages'),///events/list'), 
          array('include_entities' => 'true',
            'count' => 100,
            'since_id' => $since_id));
```

I've both tried old direct_messages and new events/list endpoints, but seems that I'm unable to download conversational messages. For example:

```
DM between person A and B:
A: Hi
B: Hello

DM between person A, B and C:
A: Hi converstion 2
B: Hello conversation 2
C: I'm new!

I expect to get some list like:
[Hi, Hello, Hi conversation 2, Hello conversation 2, I'm new!]

But I get:
[Hi, Hello]
```

Is there any way to handle this? I can't find the reason why I can't get messages from the conversation from 3 or more twitter users...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API does not support group messaging. This feature is only available through the web site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the API does not support just having the messages' text or id?

Comment: No. Group messages appear to be completely separate from normal DMs.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using API v2, see this link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/direct-messages/lookup/introduction

You can use GET /2/dm_events to retrieve all DMs associated with the current user, and then GET /2/dm_conversations/:dm_conversation_id/dm_events for a particular conversation